# Question marks folder when I turn on my mac

Tags: macos, hard-drive, crash, startup

I recently tried to reinstall macOS on my MacBook Air 2017 (Catalina) because it was slow and full of problems (for example, I didn't have any disk space though I had deleted and uninstalled everything).
So I started to follow a tutorial: I launched my device by going to my mac recovery, "Disk utility" and I deleted all the data in my Macintosh disk.

I don't know why, but my mac turned off. When I turned it back on, I saw a [question mark inside a folder](https://support.apple.com/en-za/HT204323).

So I turned on my mac again, and I pressed `CMD` + `r`. I see a progress bar with a planet. It seems to work for now. But after that, when the progress bar is loading with the apple logo, there is a startup sound, the screen becomes completely black, and it comes back to the question mark inside a folder.

I also followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSvpTgqKWVM). The unique difference is that I press `alt` rather than `cmd` + `r`. I select my wifi, and the downloading of the OS seems to work again, but still the same issue.

**Here is a [video of the issue](https://vimeo.com/user124204940/review/463438410/e51bf10e18).**

I tried again and again, the same thing happens everytime, at the same level of loading.
I already tried to [reset the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063), but it changes nothing.

If you have a possible solution to share me... thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials, it finally worked. If you are having the same issue make sure you have a good internet connection.